# Monotouch Custom UITableViewCell xCode4

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios

How can I create a custom UITableViewCell using Monotouch/Xamarin and xCode4?

I ran across this description http://www.alexyork.net/blog/post/Creating-Custom-UITableViewCells-with-MonoTouch-the-correct-way.aspx (see Peter's response)but when I run the application, all reference within the cell are null.

So If I have a UILabel in the UITableViewCell and I run the application, any outlets I created indicate null.

Regards,

Dan

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at Miguel de Icaza's blog entry about [creating custom UITableViewCells](http://tirania.org/monomac/archive/2011/Jan-18.html).

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote a blog post describing how to create a UITableView with a custom UITableViewCell, using MonoTouch and Xcode 4 (in what I believe is the best way).

In the post I show you how to set up a UITableView and also how to design your custom cell xib files using Xcode 4. I also uploaded a sample project on GitHub, hope it can be of help!

You can find everything here: http://www.arcticmill.com/2012/05/uitableview-with-custom-uitableviewcell.html

/Johan

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is very much preferred that you give the solution *here*, not just tell us that we might find it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I just followed the examples on xamarins homepage http://samples.xamarin.com/Details/iOS/05e33228-333b-4150-b596-cd7696277a3c and that pretty much showed everything. Just need one file for your custom layout and then reference that from you GetCell method.